# How do you read the mouse button state from /dev/input/mice?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

How do you read the mouse button state from /dev/input/mice? I want to detect if the button is pressed down.

Comment: What's the context of your code?  Any reason you can't use XMouse?

Comment: I am using Qt Embedded 4.6. The reason I wanted to read the state is because I cannot rely on the mouse events of Qt. The mouse release event is sometimes not received by the widget. Instead of using a flag and qt mouse events to keep track of the button state, I would to read the state as close as possible from the HW.

Comment: Off topic: Sounds like a bug to me, if you don't get the events. Wouldn't it be better to be able to trust Qt and not have to do a workaround?

Comment: I'll try a different approach then and let Qt handle it.

Comment: Even if I let Qt handle it seems that it is not able to receive the MouseReleaseEvent sometimes.

Comment: This maybe a hardware bug, but I need a software workaround for this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can open the device and read from it.  Events from /dev/input/mice are 3 bytes long and require some parsing.  I think the prefered method now is to use /dev/input/event# instead.  However, here is a small example using /dev/input/mice.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd, bytes;
    unsigned char data[3];

    const char *pDevice = "/dev/input/mice";

    // Open Mouse
    fd = open(pDevice, O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("ERROR Opening %s\n", pDevice);
        return -1;
    }

    int left, middle, right;
    signed char x, y;
    while(1)
    {
        // Read Mouse     
        bytes = read(fd, data, sizeof(data));

        if(bytes > 0)
        {
            left = data[0] & 0x1;
            right = data[0] & 0x2;
            middle = data[0] & 0x4;

            x = data[1];
            y = data[2];
            printf("x=%d, y=%d, left=%d, middle=%d, right=%d\n", x, y, left, middle, right);
        }   
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

One mouse click generates this:

```
x=0, y=0, left=1, middle=0, right=0
x=0, y=0, left=0, middle=0, right=0
```

And one mouse move (Note the "relative" mouse move coordinates):

```
x=1, y=1, left=0, middle=0, right=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You might find that `open("/dev/input/mice", ...)` fails if you don't have write access to the file (typically true as a non-admin user). You would need `sudo` to open it.

Comment: how do you get mouse up event from data ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar application to what @JustinB suggested - however in `python`

```py
import struct

with open("/dev/input/mice", mode="rb") as f:
    while True:
        button, x, y = struct.unpack('BBB', f.read(3))
        print('x={:3}, y= {:3}, button= {:08b}'.format(x, y, button))
```