# How to read input events directly from /dev/input/* in linux

Tags: linux, events

i want to develop a simple application without a GUI in c++ which detects mouse up and mouse down events in linux .I have no idea about how to read input events directly from /dev/input/* in linux , any pointers on how to proceed will be great .

---

**Also, Links to any tutorials/articles will be greatly appreciated .**

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use [gpm](http://www.nico.schottelius.org/software/gpm/)?

Comment: I never heard of it , it looks interesting . Can you describe with an example or something about how to use gpm . I am completely new with linux .

Comment: many (most?) Linux distros come with gpm, so it should just be a matter of enabling it.  [This tutorial](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gpm.xml) shows the steps needed.  Many console mode programs will be based on [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) - also standard on I think every distro - so reacting to mouse events will at the low level be handled by curses.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060710/format-of-dev-input-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you read the mouse button state from /dev/input/mice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451618/how-do-you-read-the-mouse-button-state-from-dev-input-mice)