# Linux/C++ Mouse Events without sudo

Tags: c++, linux

I need to detect if the left mouse button is clicked and then released. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451618/how-do-you-read-the-mouse-button-state-from-dev-input-mice) question using /dev/input/mice however i'd need to run the program with sudo to make it work which i want to avoid.

Comment: You can control the permissions on devices under /dev with udev rules. Where/how exactly you do that depends on the distro and version.

Comment: What kind of environment are you running? In particular, do you have a GUI running?

Comment: I'm running Arch, my programm isnt supposed to have any gui i want to make a small screenshot tool. Its working but i feel like needing the user to run a screenshot program with sudo doesnt feel right.