# Event handlers?

Tags: c, event-handling

I am using given code to handle mouse clicks. However, this is not working. I have gone through input.h to figure it out but I couldn't. bytes is 1 when it reaches if condition, but my code still doesnt allow execution to go inside if condition. What is that is being done wrong here:

```
const char *mfile = "/dev/input/mice";

int main()
{
int fd, bytes;
struct input_event data;

fd = open(mfile, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
if(fd == -1)
{
    printf("ERROR Opening associated device file: /dev/input/mice \n");
    return -1;
}

while(1)
{ 
    bytes = read(fd, &data, sizeof(struct input_event));

    if(bytes > 0)
    {
     if((data.code == BTN_LEFT) && (data.value == 0))
                printf("Left pressed. \n");                    
         else if((data.code == BTN_RIGHT) && (data.value == 0))
        printf("Right presseed. \n");
    }   
}
close(fd);
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I'd expect `if (bytes > 0)` --> `if (bytes == sizeof data)` to issue all expected data was read.  Also always print _something_ when any data read.

Comment: Doesnt work. I printed bytes and it prints 1, which is greater than 0 so it should go in if condition

Comment: When `bytes == 1`, and the `(data.code == BTN_LEFT) && (data.value == 0)` is false, what do you think code should do with the input it just read?  Ignore/discard it, save it for later?

Comment: Print “left released” when left button is released. Print “right released” when right button is released.

Comment: If only 1 byte was read, then `data` was not fully read.  With insufficient information read, it does not make sense to try and access the members `.code` and `.value` as those members will not   be completely assigned. Code needs a new approach.

Comment: this is pretty much my only approach left. I had another approach where I am doing this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451618/how-do-you-read-the-mouse-button-state-from-dev-input-mice
Problem with this one is that, left mouse release and right mouse release both generate "8". which becomes a problem to handle.

Comment: Its not that I cannot make it work using the code given in above linked stackoverflow post, but that ll make me write 4 if conditions and then 2 variable to do so. I want to keep it optimized. Was wondering if there is a linux header file that can do it for me. Input.h above, the method above doesnt work me. I hope you get my problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to wait until `read` has read input the size of `input_event` structure before you process the data in it.

But the current code only checks if any bytes have been read. This check should be changed to check if the number of bytes read equals the `input_event` structure.

See the documentation of [read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read):.

> Return Value.
>
> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number. **It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now** (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately. In this case it is left unspecified whether the file position (if any) changes.